# Does boss difficulty change depending on the floor?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

In Splatoon 3 Side Order, because of the randomization of the tower, there are three bosses that can be fought on either floor 10 or 20 (Asynchronous Rondo, Pinging Marciale, and Parallel Canon).

Does these boss fights have any differences based on what floor you fight them on? In other words, if I fight Asynchronous Rondo on floor 20, will the fight be harder than if I'd fought it on floor 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, boss difficulty does change depending on if you fight a boss on floor 10F or 20F.

- Pinging Marciale

  - Ramming attack will drop Suction Bombs on 20F.
  - Splat Bombs drop one at a time on 10F and three at a time on 20F.
- Parallel Cannon

  - Number of enemies per wave increases by 1 on floor 20F. (10F is 1, 2, and 4, 20F is 2, 3, and 5)
  - Amount of armor cases lowered (3 on 10F, 1 on 20F).
- Asynchronous Rondo

  - Unsure what changes, if anything.

Sources:

- Inkipeda, the Splatoon Wiki ([Pinging Miracle](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Pinging_Marciale) and [Parallel Cannon](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Parallel_Canon))
- NintednoBase: [Splatoon 3 Side Order - All Bosses + Ending](https://youtu.be/t29CWDRVLm8?t=616)
- Personal playtime.